# Finding an empty input box using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have multiple input boxes on a webpage with the following xPaths:

```
//*[@id="swatch-visual-options-panel"]/table/tbody/tr[1478]/td[4]/input

//*[@id="swatch-visual-options-panel"]/table/tbody/tr[1480]/td[4]/input

//*[@id="swatch-visual-options-panel"]/table/tbody/tr[1481]/td[4]/input
```

One of which is empty and all the others have text inside them.
As you may have guessed, there are 1481 elements with the previous xPath pattern but I only want to locate the empty one.

How do I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Answer (score 1):

You'd grab all the trs and then go through them and find empty ones.

```
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='swatch-visual-options-panel']/table/tbody/tr")
lst=[]
for tr in trs:   
    elem = tr.find_element_by_xpath("/td[4]/input")
    if(len(elem.text)==0):
       lst.append(elem)
```

Comment: Gives no such element found exception at   ``elem = tr.find_element_by_xpath("/td[4]/input")``

Comment: Is this after page loading use a webdriver wait.

Answer (score 1):

Among the multiple input boxes on the webpage to locate the `<input>` element without any text you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
//*[@id="swatch-visual-options-panel"]/table/tbody/tr[1481]/td[4]/input[not(contains(text()))]
```